# Android Application that give timing advance and AOA

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is any application on Android that gives the timing advance and maybe the angle of arrival.

If not, maybe a way of doing it would be very helpful.

Comment: What Are You Talking About And Why Is Every Word Capitalized?

Comment: The timing advance is the length of time a signal takes to reach the base station from a mobile phone. This might clarify what i want :http://www.gsm-modem.de/gsm-location.html. 

More or less something like that but less complicated : http://www.nobbi.com/monitor/nokwen.html.

Comment: as for the every word capitalized >> http://theclearcopywriter.com/copywriting/why-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word/

Comment: Setting aside that SO is not a marketing tool, and therefore so called "copy writing" has absolutely no place here, you've made your question appallingly difficult to read.

Comment: I doubt that SO is the right forum for such a question.  As for the second part, you need to try doing some research and show some development effort before forum members can try to help.

Comment: I was making sure that the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111796/get-mobile-cell-tower-timing-advance-on-android-2-3

Comment: is dead and there is noway to do such a thing

Answer (score 0):

@peter Me too looking for same concept. I researched on that we can calculate the timing advance using Propagation time .. it should result in 3.69 (mu s)units from that we can able to calculate the Distance between the BS and MS ... 300 * 3.69/2 = approx 553 m..   But we need to find **PROPAGATION TIME** if u have some idea share with me. I dont have 50 rep so i cant give comment.. so i post this as answer. Sorry