# How to get timing advance value in android?

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, windows-8, android-ndk

I am getting MCC,MNC,LAC values in Android apps, and even I made my own application and I am able to obtain these values.

But Timing Advance (TA) is not available in any of the app or I am not finding any way to get TA. I can use NDK, or AT commands or SDK anything, but I want to get TA value.

Can you suggest any pointers. If not Android, I am OK with iPhone, or Windows App also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Same questions here [Get mobile cell tower timing advance on Android 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111796/get-mobile-cell-tower-timing-advance-on-android-2-3)

For LTE technology there is already an access to Timing Advance values: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthLte.html#getTimingAdvance()

No SDK access method for GSM and UMTS.
AT commands are modem specific...

Answer (score 0):

For **LTE**, TA is available through `getTimingAdvance ()`, starting from API **17** (AOS 4.2 - Jelly Bean).